# python pyxb UnrecognizedDOMRootNodeError(node)

Tags: python, xml, labview, pyxb

I am trying to create a pyxb module from the LabVIEW schema.  Using the module I am getting an UnrecognizedDOMRootNodeError:

> > ```
> > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > File "X:\Projects\LV-PY\Python\LV-PY\pyXB\testXML.py", line 14, in <module>
> >   fc_return = cluster.CreateFromDOM(doc.documentElement)
> > File "X:\Projects\LV-PY\Python\LV-PY\pyXB\cluster.py", line 76, in 
> >  CreateFromDOM
> > return pyxb.binding.basis.element.AnyCreateFromDOM(node, default_namespace)
> > File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyxb\binding\basis.py", line 1743, in 
> >  AnyCreateFromDOM
> > return cls.CreateDOMBinding(node, expanded_name.elementBinding(), 
> >     _fallback_namespace=fallback_namespace)
> > File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyxb\binding\basis.py", line 1705, in   
> >     CreateDOMBinding
> > raise pyxb.UnrecognizedDOMRootNodeError(node)
> >    pyxb.exceptions_.UnrecognizedDOMRootNodeError: <pyxb.utils.saxdom.Element
> >    object at 0x0625F9D0>
> > ```

Since the LabVIEW schema is huge, I made a small sample of it with just a Cluster containing a string:

```
<xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:lv="http://www.ni.com/labview" elementFormDefault="qualified"
targetNamespace="http://www.ni.com/labview"
xmlns="http://www.ni.com/labview">

<!--Root element that contains all other data-->
<!--will NOT be produced by primitive-->
<xsd:element name="LVData" type="lv:LVDataRootType"/>
<xsd:complexType name="LVDataRootType">
  <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xsd:element name="Cluster" type="lv:ClusterType"/>
    <xsd:element name="String" type="lv:StringType"/>
  </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>

<!--Basic elements-->

<xsd:complexType name="StringType">
  <xsd:complexContent>
    <xsd:extension base="lv:LVDataType"/>
   </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="LVDataType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element name="Val" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<!--Cluster element-->
<xsd:complexType name="ClusterType">
  <xsd:sequence>  
      <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="NumElts" type="xsd:unsignedByte"/>
        <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:element name="String" type="lv:StringType"/>
        </xsd:choice>
   </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

Then I sent the XML output from a simple LabVIEW cluster:

```
<Cluster>
<Name>clTest</Name>
<NumElts>1</NumElts>
<String>
<Name>sTest</Name>
<Val>foo</Val>
</String>
</Cluster>
```

I'm guessing the problem is related to pabigot's reply from: [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758240/pyxb-unrecognizeddomrootnodeerror)

> in XML Schema namespaces for elements and types are distinct, but in Python
>   they are not,

But I'm not so sure. Do I need to change the ***lv:...Type*** throughout the LabView Schema to have the same name and type?

In other words, rather than:

```
    <xsd:element name="Cluster" type="lv:ClusterType"/>
```

should I have:

```
    <xsd:element name="Cluster" type="Cluster"/>
```

This would be a major change to the LabVIEW schema, which does this sort of thing throughout.

Comment: Follow on:  I tried changing the element linesas shown and it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your document.  The schema expects a top-level element `{http://www.ni.com/labview}LVData`, while your document has a top-level element `Cluster`.  You need to wrap your document, and add a namespace declaration.  The document below does not produce an error.

```
<LVData xmlns="http://www.ni.com/labview">
  <Cluster>
    <Name>clTest</Name>
    <NumElts>1</NumElts>
    <String>
      <Name>sTest</Name>
      <Val>foo</Val>
    </String>
  </Cluster>
</LVData>
```